# StackExchange.com IP from Google DNS doesn't work, BUT IP from Whois Database works

Tags: ip, dns

There is a strange issue in my office building.

According to Google DNS `8.8.8.8`, StackExchange.com and StackOverflow.com IP address is `198.252.206.16`.

**Outside of the building's** internet connection, no problems, **but inside of the building**, the site cannot be reached.

**Now here is the weird part**. Whois info (http://whois.domaintools.com/stackexchange.com) shows the IP address of the server as `104.16.12.128` (different from Google DNS) and when I manually edit my host file and point those domains there, **it works!**

Something is seriously strange. My first guess is that my building's IP has been blocked and pointing to the IP in the Whois info circumvents this block.

Can anyone explain why this is happening?

*My building IP is 115.89.231.130*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Updating with answer.

If my memory serves me correctly, a while back we contacted StackExchange and they found that our IP had been blocked for some unknown reason. When they unblocked it, it worked.

We had just moved into that building at that time and was just newly assigned that IP (115.89.231.130). Our assumption is that someone previously on that IP may have triggered the block prior to us receiving the IP.

Answer (score 1):

The ip address 104.16.12.128 is owned by CloudFlare. StackExchange use(s/d) CloudFlare as DDoS mitigation service.

198.252.206.16 is the correct ip address for stackexchange as tested with stackexchange dns server (cf-dns01.stackexchange.com)

Could there be a firewall policy in place with certain blocked ip ranges (e.g. CloudFlare - which would explain your issue)?

Comment: According to the ISP, there isn't any firewall in place that blocks the stackexchange IP or a range including it. I am almost convinced there is some kind of block that exists on StackExchange that doesn't exist on CloudFlare preventing my building's IP from connecting. Do you think that is a reasonable assumption?